# How to get multiple value out of while loop to use in query outside the loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get multiple values outside the while loop to use it in the query outside the while loop also. Now I can just get one value at a time. The values that I'm trying to get is this one `$ids=$row["curriculum_id"];`

This is my code, any help would be highly appreciated.

```
  <?php

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']) AND $_POST['Submit'] == 'Submit')
    {

   $coursneededdate =$_POST['needed']; 
$coursneededdate =mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$coursneededdate);
$gradunder=$_POST['gradunder']; 
$gradunder =mysqli_real_escape_string ($mysqli,$gradunder);
$avalablesemster= $_POST['avalable'];
$avalablesemster =mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$avalablesemster);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM curriculum where '".$coursneededdate."' between  startdate and enddate";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $ids=$row["curriculum_id"];

        }


    }
    }

    $result2 ="SELECT * FROM  curriculumcourses  INNER JOIN courses ON curriculumcourses.course_id = courses.course_id where curriculum_id='$ids' and semester_ava='$avalablesemster'";

    $result3 = $mysqli->query($result2);
    if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);


        }

        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rough version (untested). This code was injectable, I've put in the mysqli_real_escape_string, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php. Consider using prepared statements in the future, [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) AND $_POST['Submit'] == 'Submit') {
    $coursneededdate = isset($_POST['needed']) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['needed']) : '';
    $gradunder=isset($_POST['gradunder']) ? $_POST['gradunder'] : ''; //this isn't used?
    $avalablesemster= isset($_POST['avalable']) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['avalable']) : '';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM curriculum where '".$coursneededdate."' between  startdate and enddate";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $ids = '';
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $ids .= $mysqli->real_escape_string($row["curriculum_id"]) . ', ';
        }
        $ids = rtrim($ids, ', ');
    }
}
$result2 ="SELECT * FROM  curriculumcourses  INNER JOIN courses ON curriculumcourses.course_id = courses.course_id where curriculum_id in($ids) and semester_ava='$avalablesemster'";
$result3 = $mysqli->query($result2);
if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($row);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
?>
```

This code is concatenating all your curriculum ids into a comma delimited listed in the `ids` variable. This variable is then used with the SQL function `in` which will search for all ids in that list. Here's 2 docs on that topic https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm.

Comment: Thank you very much @chris85 I appreciate your help. I was editing my post to use real_escape_string. About this one $gradunder I will start to try to use it to filter data depending in its value.

Comment: Okay, be sure to escape that as well. I wasn't sure if that was used somewhere so I didn't escape it.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace both queries for just one:

```
SELECT * FROM  curriculumcourses  
    NATURAL JOIN courses  
    WHERE  semester_ava='$avalablesemster' 
    AND curriculum_id IN (
        SELECT curriculum_id 
        FROM curriculum 
        WHERE '".$coursneededdate."' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate)
```

And then directly fetch the result from it.

This solutions is faster because the DBMS optimize the queries. Also, the option of `query -> PHP -> query -> PHP` it's more difficult to debug, read and maintain (in addition to be slower).